# javascript registerElement usage

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, custom-element

Recently discovered `document.registerElement`
it seems nice that I can encapsulate bunch of HTML and JS code in an element.
How can I for example create an element that will be a bootstrap modal:

```
<bootstrap-modal>
<modal-header></modal-header>
<modal-body></modal-body>
</bootstrap-modal>
```

instead of inserting a lot of html that the modal requires.
And I would need one for dropdown :

```
<dropdown>
<option href=""></option>
</dropdown>
```

Is this good to declare elements like that?
If so, why this method is not in common use? In most websites I just see bunch of divs and spans with many classes..

Comment: It´s quite new so several browsers don´t support it and many people don´t know about them. If you would like to use them, would recommend looking at polymer library

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good to declare elements like that.

It's not in common use because most browsers [don't implement it yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements).

However [there's a polyfill](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) if you want to make them work in other browsers.

It will change soon because Custom Elements are now integrated in the [HTLM Living Standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements).

A good start to create your first custom element is to read [this article about Custom Elements v1](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/customelements/)*.

**Note:* the `registerElement` is being replaced by a new function called `defineElement`, you'll need at least Chrome v53 to make it work.

Comment: Did you found an answer to your question?